# When is an IP replaced in routing?

Tags: networking, router, ip, routing

If I have 2 networks, `192.168.1.0/24` and `192.168.2.0/24`, and my IP is `192.168.1.2` with the following routes:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

Why when reaching a host in the `192.168.2.3` it detects my IP `192.168.1.2`?

What should happen for `192.168.2.3` to detect the router's IP instead (`192.168.1.254`)? Is it another type of network?

Thanks

Comment: in the situation you describe, never.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why when reaching a host in the 192.168.2.3 it detects my IP 192.168.1.2?

The IP address is *never* replaced in normal routing. (Only the MAC addresses are.)

That's why sites like "What's my IP?" can see your IP despite being behind a dozen routers.

> What should happen for 192.168.2.3 to detect the router's IP instead (192.168.1.254)?

You would have to enable the NAT function (network address translation) on the router. (On Linux, it is also called masquerading.)

Most of the time, NAT is undesirable and usually only makes things worse; don't use it when routing between LANs unless it's absolutely required for some reason.

Comment: If you use NAT in private - private, you would not be able to reach any of the second lan IPs? I mean, you would not know what is behind the NATting IP? So, you would only have 1 IP to reach and the ports being NATed?

Comment: Well, no, if you still have a route towards the NATed subnet, then you can still send packets towards it. The NAT by itself won't prevent that, only additional firewall rules would (e.g. conntrack).

Answer (score 1):

An IP is replaced if there is [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) (NAT) in the mix. The rough outline of it is that the IPs you specified it the question are both in the [pool of private IP addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces), so there will be no NAT in the picture (unless you for some weird reason has your router to NAT/Masquerade anyway). This means that if both machines in question have public routable IPs, then no IPs will be replaced either.

However, if the source IP is from a private IP, then NAT will take effect (provided that it is enabled on the router), and the router will replace your local IP to its own public IP.

Comment: Note that NAT is not specific to the "private → public" case, nor does it happen automatically when routing between private and public ranges; it's just most often used in such situations... (there are various networks which do public/public or private/private NAT, as well as networks where private addresses can reach public ones without being NATed, though of course still within the same network)

Comment: @grawity hence why I said "rough outline" in my answer. There are pretty much always exceptions or gray areas.